# Select Distinct Not In Select Distinct Returning 0 Rows, Should be almost 1000

Tags: t-sql, distinct

```
Select Distinct FileId From dbo.Files
```

returns 3415 rows

```
Select Distinct FileId From dbo.SyncHistory Where Date > '2015/7/1'
```

returns 2483 rows.

```
Select Distinct FileId From dbo.Files 
Where FileId In (Select Distinct FileId From dbo.SyncHistory Where Date > '2015/7/1')
```

returns 248**2** rows. Okay so someone synced this month but then deleted their file I assume.

BUT:

```
Select Distinct FileId From dbo.Files 
Where FileId NOT In (Select Distinct FileId From dbo.SyncHistory Where Date > '2015/7/1')
```

Returns **0 rows**.

I thought my connection was broken but I've run and rerun it and the results are consistent if also consistently wrong. Is this a sql bug? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possibly about the null's in the FileId column. Please check the nulls both in the inner and outer query executing them separately. If you find nulls then the following should work:

```
Select Distinct FileId From dbo.Files 
Where FileId In (Select Distinct FileId From dbo.SyncHistory Where Date > '2015/7/1' 
AND FileId IS NOT NULL)

Select Distinct FileId From dbo.Files 
Where FileId NOT In (Select Distinct FileId From dbo.SyncHistory Where Date > '2015/7/1' 
AND FileId IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: This does work but what about the null causes the Not In stop working?

Comment: William: For the explanation please refer the duplicate what is referred. It's the right explanation. My answer is adding a solution how to workaround this correct but weird behavior. In case that the explanation is not clear for you there, I am glad to explain here, trying it with other words, or more details.

Comment: I did see the duplicate afterwards and read the explanation there, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT DISTINCT
a.FileID
FROM dbo.Files a
LEFT JOIN
(Select Distinct FileId From dbo.SyncHistory Where Date > '2015/7/1') b
ON a.FileID = b.FileID
WHERE b.FileID IS NULL
```